# Slick slider center mode

Tags: jquery, css, slick.js

Ребята, нужно реализовать такую карусель
[image: карусель]

Вот нашла такой код https://codepen.io/RhinoLu/pen/grKbKW?editors=1010
, но мне не нужно что бы была центральная картинка. Не знаю как это сделать. Может подскажите и вовсе другой вариант. Буду признательна.

Comment: Как понять "не нужно чтобы была центральная картинка"? Вы хотите четыре итема видеть вместо трех? Или нужно убрать фокус с центрального элемента? Slick достаточно хороший, и вполне может решить вашу задачу

Comment: документация http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Исправьте ссылку в вопросе

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 0):

[Slick Слайдер](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick) c `centerMode:true`:

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,               
  dots: false,
  arrows:false,
  infinite: true, 
  //variableWidth: true,  
  centerMode:true
});
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  border:1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="slider">
    <div>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: спасибо, но выдает ошибку и все position смещаются(Chrom), а в Opera совсем нет карусели. Oшибка: Uncaught TypeError: _.$list.on is not a function. не подскажите в чем проблема?

Comment: @maRIAM. Вы тут видите ошибку? Логично предположить что в ваших скриптах где-то ошибка